# Can I use IPv6 connectivity through openVPN if my router does not support it?

Tags: openvpn, router, ipv6

Can I use IPv6 connectivity through openVPN if my router and my ISP does not support it but my openVPN server does?

Comment: I would say yes, according to Cisco:  http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-version-6/25156-ipv6tunnel.html

Comment: Would preferred to used a tunnel through gogoc command or via an explicitly set up tunnel, like through Hurricane Electric. Gogo uses encryption och signature so you know that you uses the right server, and HE uses an explicitly set IPv4 address that it only allows to use their tunnel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists an [IPv6 mapping to every existing IPc4 connection](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6IPv4AddressEmbedding-2.htm)

So if your router and ISP are running an IPv4  link to you, openVPN should have no problems making an IPv6 link.

Thus yes.